# "TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation"

Tags: python, exception

In what cases would Python throw this error:

```
"TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation"
```

The error was reported in this line of code:

```
csv.reader(open(file_name), dialect=dialect)
```

I've tried to reproduce it but the closest I got was this error:

```
"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found"
```

I've tried with Python2.7 and Python 2.5 on Linux and Python 2.4 on Windows XP

Comment: If you encountered this message, you should have gotten a traceback with it.

Comment: I was reported to me but I can't reproduce it, the closest I get is a different error. That is why I would like to know in what cases this error should appear.

Comment: Are the error messages from the same Python version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv.reader` in Python 2.4 has known bugs; see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-January/059758.html

In general, "bad argument type for built-in operation" crops up all over the place because it's the exception text generated by [`PyErr_BadArgument`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dc18a2a66d16/Python/errors.c#l357) CPython API call.  This means that the traceback won't be much use because the exception is raised in C code.  Your best bet for debugging is to run Python under a debugger and set a breakpoint on `PyErr_BadArgument`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `file_name` is a bool instead of a string or buffer like `open()` expects.  I wouldn't be very concerned with the differing messages; they are both TypeErrors, one just happens to be more specific than the other, probably because of some difference in Python version.